# Tensorflow parameter convergence

Tags: tensorflow

I am minimizing a stochastic loss function `energy` using an optimizer in Tensorflow.  I haven't been able to find a way to keep an old copy of my parameters, but I'd like to stop training when my parameters (rather than my loss function) converges.  E.g if I was only training `mu` I'd like to do something like

`sess.run(tf.while_loop(mu_converged, update, [(mu, mu_old)]))`

rather than

`for _ in range(1000):
   sess.run(optimizer.train(loss))`

Thanks!